# SQLAlchemy injecting data into a query result to be inserted into another table

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I've found a question on how to insert values from a table into another table:

[SQLAlchemy: Inserting the results of a query into another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070733/sqlalchemy-inserting-the-results-of-a-query-into-another-table)

My query is is slightly different.

When running a SQL you can do something like this:

```
insert into table1(col1, col2)
   select some_constant_value_or_variable, col2 from table2;
```

Is there a way to do this in SQLAlchemy

Comment: Is your question regarding using the SQLAlchemy ORM? If not, you could just execute the the SQL query to construct the new table using `cursor.execute(...)`

Comment: @R.Arctor It is.  If I wanted to use straight connection I could have run everything without it.

Comment: @Karlson - How is your desired SQL statement different from the one in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22290468/2144390)? Is it the `some_constant_value_or_variable` bit?

Comment: @GordThompson Because `some_constant_value_or_variable` is a constant that may but more then likely will not exist inside a database.  More then likely this will be a python variable.

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal_column

Comment: @GordThompson Not by itself.  I can't seem to have a `literal_column` to return value under a particular label.

Comment: @Karlson - [This](https://pastebin.com/k3Jg9vMc) works for me.

Comment: Can you post the answer or the call?